# How does high external debt hurt GDP?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-economics, debt, balance-of-payments

Really confused by this. Say debt burdens increase and country A now has to spend more of its income towards servicing its debt to country B, causing a fall in consumption. Country B now has more money to spend on buying goods and services from A though which should make up for the fall in consumption in A by increasing exports, leaving GDP unchanged.

Obviously that’s not what has happened in debt crises like the Greek one as GDP has fallen dramatically so what exactly am I missing?

Comment: It's probably a bad assumption that B's imports from A increase by the amount  of the increase in debt of A multiplied by the interest rate.  Are you assuming a simplified economy where B is the rest of the world that is not A?  Are you assuming that country C exists or that other countries exist?  B can import more from C.  Are you assuming B cannot borrow from C ?

Comment: Too much for one comment so I'm continuing here...  It's also a bad assumption that B's imports from A is constrained by the interest payment (and in the non-steady state, the principle repayment). The debt service cash flows of A do not necessarily increase when the debt burden increases. For example A can simply stop paying.